# When is the product of two arbitray matrices symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a real $n \times m$ matrix. Let $\mathbf{B}$ be a real $m \times n$ matrix. How to solve the following matrix equation?  $$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B^{t}}\mathbf{A^{t}}$$

Obviously, $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{A^{t}}$ solves the above equations. How to find all other possible solutions if they exist?

Comment: Which one is the unknown?

Comment: I think (outside of a few "trivial" examples) that this is horribly underdetermined.

Comment: $AB_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m a_{ik}b_{kj}$, while $B^tA^t_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{kj}$.
The equation is determined for the set of matrices $A$ and $B$ such that for every $i, j$ it holds $\sum_{k=1}^m a_{ik}b_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{kj}$
There are infinitely many examples.

Comment: @Alex Well we can fix one, say $\mathbf{A}$. But this comes from a condition on a pair of matrices.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes it does. But it looks similar to commutativity. I was wondering if there was a way to characterize such matrices in the same fashion it is done for commutative matrices (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Commuting_matrices)

Comment: @Drmanifold oh I see. Maybe you should rephrase your post slightly to reflect that this is what you are looking for. *That* is definitely an interesting question.

Comment: It is a lot more flabby than commuting matrices. Given $(A,B)$ a pair. Note that if $S$ is a symmetric matrix, then $(A,SB)$ and $(AS,B)$ are also pairs. If $C$ is invertible, then $(AC, C^{-1} B)$ is also a pair. For $E$ arbitrary, $(E^TA, BE)$ and $(A E^T, EB)$ are also pairs.

Comment: A possibility is that perhaps all solutions $(A,B)$ can be generated from $(O, O^t)$ using the above listed transformations. But whether that is in fact true I don't know.

Comment: Actually, quite obviously my previous comment does not cover all bases. Let $(A,B)$ be a pair and suppose that $A$ has a non-vanishing kernel. Then there exists non-zero $C$ such that $AC = 0$. Then $(A,B+C)$ is another pair. This has the side effect that the set of solutions you are looking for is not a submanifold, since the "tangent space" changes dimensions depending on where you are.